# How can I create a better-looking GUI that's not pixelated and old looking?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to find a better interface, or better method to draw stuff on Java, basic stuff like lines, strings and shapes, they all turn out very pixeled and old looking, id like to improve that.

the more it is related to an existing java package, the better.

Comment: http://www.jidesoft.com/products/download.htm

Comment: Which gui toolkit are you using now? Swing? SWT? AWT??

Comment: They have a [common layer](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm) open source and other components that yes, costs money.

Comment: Im using swing, Graphics class mostly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [Java 2D](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-1998/jw-08-media.html). You can set the drawing to render at higher quality via the setRenderingHints function. (If you turn on anti-aliasing you won't see such jagged lines on your draw items.)

From the linked article:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                          RenderingHints.ANTIALIAS_ON);
    // draw shapes...
}
```

Comment: +1 I was in the middle of typing this myself.

Comment: "ANTIALIASING cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: BTW, after this works, Do u have any suggestion about improving Strings looks?

Comment: @OfekRon: Yes, same method, slightly different hints: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/renderinghints.html

Comment: @OfekRon: For your error, check here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html It looks like `ANTIALIASING ` should be `KEY_ANTIALIASING `

Comment: Thanks, that looks way better now, btw the problem was that the class is RenderingHints not Graphics2D as you said at first, but thanks man!

Comment: One little change is that I always override `paintComponent` instead of `paint` when I do custom paint methods.  I'm not exactly sure why.

Answer (score -2):

if you want to stay at java domain, maybe you should try [Java FX](http://javafx.com/)? I know its not pure java, but its pretty close...

Comment: -1 this would require a lot of effort to learn a whole new system.  Antialiasing solves the problem and doesn't require anything more than the addition of one line of code.